# Convert low pass continuous time filter design to bandpass, discrete time

Tags: filter-design, lowpass-filter, dsp-core, transfer-function, bilinear-transform

I am trying to convert the continuous time transfer function of a second order lowpass Butterworth filter is given by:
[image: LP Transfer function]

To a bandpass fourth order bandpass digital filter, I first apply the mapping to bandpass:
[image]

We therefore obtain the bandpass continuous time transfer function

[image]

In order to convert this to a digital filter with with band edge frequencies of 2000Hz and 2819.3 Hz, and a sampling rate of 8 kHz. We first normalise and apply bilinear prewarping

[image]

[image]

approximating slightly we get

[image]

Then applying the bilinear transform

[image]

We get the fourth order discrete time filter
[image]

**However**
Checking the results at the normalised angular frequencies 0 and at the bandpass center frequency 3, I find that the frequency response is not as desired. is this an arithmetic mistake or have I missed something, your help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the analog bandpass filter transfer function. If you apply the LP-BP transformation as you stated it you should get the following transfer function:

$$H(s)=\frac{s^2(\Omega_2-\Omega_1)^2}{s^4+\sqrt{2}(\Omega_2-\Omega_1)s^3+(\Omega_1^2+\Omega_2^2)s^2+\sqrt{2}\Omega_1\Omega_2(\Omega_2-\Omega_1)s+\Omega_1^2\Omega_2^2}$$

With the given band edge frequencies (note that the lower band edge of the discrete-time filter must be $2000\,\text{Hz}$, not $4000\,\text{Hz}$) you correctly got $\Omega_1=2$ and $\Omega_2=4$. Applying the bilinear transform to the analog bandpass transfer function with these band edges finally gives the following discrete-time transfer function:

$$H(z)=\frac{z^4-2z^2+1}{(10+3\sqrt{2})z^4+(12+2\sqrt{2})z^3+20z^2+(12-2\sqrt{2})z+10-3\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Ah thanks, it was just an arithmetic mistake, I wasnt sure.